# Is win-unpacked folder necessary when deploying an electron app on my server

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I wish to avoid deploying the win-unpacked folder, 
but since I do not if it is of any use by the Auto-Update feature,
I keep deploying it.

1. So when this win-unpacked folder is needed ?
2. What feature will I loose if I am not providing it on my deployed server ?

Thx

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I am trying to understand the purpose of the win-unpacked folder.

Comment: for an in detail explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68396336/4316681